# Ratchet PHP reconnect client who loose connection

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, ratchet

I have a chat application made with Ratchet PHP. This application work like a charm except when I loose my connection. For my test I connect my phone to the application and disable wifi and 4G. I see on the documentation that I need to use enableKeepAlive, it wait for reconnection but never reconnect or create a new connection when the user try to send a message after having internet back.
Someone can explain me how to reconnect my client without reload the page ? I don't understand and doesn't found nothing when I search.
PS : I put you the code I think important and don't share you all the code, so don't be afraid if you don't understand how work my chat :)

My connection code :

```
<?php
namespace MySite;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Connection implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function sendAll(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s"' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');
        $from->send($msg);
    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

My Ratchet application code :

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MySite\Connection;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        $wsServer = new WsServer(
            new Connection()
        )
    ),
    8081
);
$wsServer->enableKeepAlive($server->loop, 30);
$server->run();
```

Comment: It's the JavaScript client which makes the connection which is more relevant - it's that code which would need to detect losing the connection and attempt to reconnect.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)
So I need to detect if the connection is lost with JS and send an other connection if i am disconnected ? 
Where can i do that ? In the ws.conn.onclose function in client side ?
Is it a propper way to put a setInterval and retry a connection ?

Comment: Thanks, you solved it.